# wxStaticBitmap above wxGauge

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like to put the image (wxStaticBitmap) which is a png file with transparency above the wxGauge. The result I would like to achieve is not rectangular progress bar. Transparency should determine the shape. Unfortunately, when value of wxGauge is changed progress bar is displayed above wxStaticBitmap. Is it possible to keep it deeper, on the 2nd layer below the image?

Answer (score 0):

No, overlapped child controls are not supported by wxWidgets because none of the platforms actually supports this well (or at least used not to, I'm not sure what is the state with the latest versions). If you want to have a non-rectangular progress bar, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: So what's the best way to do it myself? Maybe I should draw a pattern on wxBufferedPaintDC?

Comment: Yes, implement your own control by deriving your own class from `wxWindow` and handling `wxEVT_PAINT` by drawing on `wxAutoBufferedPaintDC`.